# Boost warnings with VC++ 9

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, warnings

When the Boost library/headers is used with VC++ 9 compilers (Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition or Visual Studio 2008), a lot of benign warnings are generated. They are of 2 kinds:

1. Warning about the Wp64 setting.
2. Warning about the compiler version.

How can I turn off these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Warning about the Wp64 setting.

   > Turn off the **/Wp64** setting which is set by default. You can find it in *Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General*.
2. Warning about the compiler version.

   > Go to the Boost trunk (online) and get the latest **boost\boost\config\compiler\visualc.hpp** header file. Diff it with the current file and merge the sections where **_MSC_VER** is equal to **1800**. (*1800* is the VC9 version number used in Boost configuration.)