# Disable /W4 warnings for boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, warnings

How can I disable all MSVC warnings that come from the boost library?

I know I can disable specific warnings where they occur etc... but it clutters my code and if I use boost macros then they don't seem to work. I would like to have a simple way to tell my compiler to not give me warnings about boost. Is this possible?

On a secondary note, I'm a bit surprised that the boost library doesn't disable all these warnings internally so that we users can use it "out of the box".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They try extremely hard to avoid warnings, but some compilers warn for code that is formally correct, just a bit "suspicious". If you change the code to silence the warning, another compiler might warn for that code!

There is a warning policy for Boost code and various compilers
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/Guidelines/WarningsGuidelines

They are also particularly careful not to disable warnings, because you might have some parts of your code where the warning is actually correct. If Boost disables the warning, you might not find the errors in your code!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the warnings for *all* projects by changing the default property pages:

- Open any project.
- Click on
  view->property manager.
- In the
  property manager (probably along the
  left bar), expand the project, then
  expand one of the profiles, then
  double-click on one of the categories
  that all your projects will be using:
  Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user,
  Application, or perhaps Core Windows
  Libraries.
- This brings up the
  *Properties* page, but for all code that you write or will write. Set the
  appropriate pre-processor definitions
  and disable /wp64 or whatever you
  need to do for an individual project.

Since it's probably not desirable to disable those warnings for all projects, it seems like you could disable warnings in visual_c.hpp as described here: [Boost warnings with VC++ 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271/boost-warnings-with-vc-9) .  But then you'll have to make the change every time you update your libraries.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to create special header-file in which to put all Boost `#include`s. These `#include`s should be surrounded with blocks of `#pragma`

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)        

#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#pragma warning(pop)
```

Disadvantage of this way: some compile-time inefficiency

Comment: A problem with this is that some of the warnings occur when you **use** the templates from the headers. At that point the warnings are back on again.

Comment: @Bo: I didn't know that before. I wonder why this is happening. Do you the reason for this? As I understand this [patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3611) fixes problems with Boost.Thread